# ArrayList + HashMap

Tags: objective-c

I have an array that contains dictionaries.

When adding new items to the array I want to either add them to the top or update the dictionary depending on if the key I'm adding exists or not. If no dictionary exist for that key I want to add it to the top. Otherwise I want to update the dictionary with that key.

How can we do this best in Objective-C?

```
NSMutableArray * mediaData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int k=0; k<mediaData.count; k++)
{
    NSDictionary   *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"String1" forKey: @"Test"];
    [mediaData add:dict];
}
```

How can we update the dictionary values if it exists with the above key (say for example "String1"), and if not how we will append to the top of the array if the dictionary with the key does not exist in the list.

Apologize if there is some syntax error in the code. It is just to make you understand what the issue is.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using `NSArray`s and `NSDictionary`s?

Comment: Am a java developer but am infact trying to use NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary in objective-c

Comment: What is the real purpose behind this? Does the dictionaries contain more keys? Otherwise it's just shuffling strings around in an array (assuming that the key is always the same)

Comment: Also, breaking it down. What is the trouble? Enumerating the array? Checking the the key exists? Inserting at a specific index? Updating an existing array?

Comment: Say, i have an arrayList of size 10. At each index i have an hashmap with unique key, and an object as value. Now, i want to update/insert the arraylist with new hashmap if does not exist, or replace the hashmap that already exists with the same key. Hope am clear now

Comment: Just as a hint, it helps if you use the vocabulary of the domain. If you are in Objective-C, that means you are talking about Arrays and dictionaries, not ArrayLists and HashMaps.

Comment: Sorry dude am out of objective c programming for a while. Am just trying to help my colleague who has this generic programming question. :)

Answer (score 2):

OK this is untested and somewhat clunky, but I think it meets your requirements:

MyList.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyList : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_array;
}

- (void)addOrUpdateObject:(NSObject *)value
                   forKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

Then the implementation will be something like:

MyList.m:

```
#import "MyList.h"

@implementation MyList

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addOrUpdateObject:(NSObject *)value
                   forKey:(NSString *)key {

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < _array.count; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [_array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *allKeys = [dict allKeys];
        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < allKeys.count; j++) {
            NSString *existingKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:j];
            if ([existingKey isEqualToString:key]) {
                [dict setObject:value forKey:key];
                return;    // Updated
            }
        }
    }

    // Key not found; create a new dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:value forKey:key];
    [_array insertObject:dict atIndex:0];
}

@end
```

Comment: +1. The code looks like it will work, but I think the whole premise of using this type of data structure is wrong and can probably be replaced with something more efficient if the OP stated why they wanted this. Not your fault, though.

Comment: Am trying to do this for updating a UITableView. I want to update the table with the latest data and replace the data if it already exists.

Comment: @user694688 That sounds like another question?

Comment: No, am having an array of tweets which am getting from twitter. The tweets have a tweet id as key in the hashmap, which is in the array. I want to insert the new tweets in the array and ignore/replace the tweets that are already there when the page re-loads. So, am thinking how to do this efficiently.

Comment: @user694688 Couldn't a single `NSDictionary` do that?  Having an array of single-entry dictionaries doesn't do anything other than complicate things.

Comment: But i want the order of tweets to be maintained. Does NSDictionary maintain the order.

Comment: @user694688 No it doesn't.

Comment: So, that is why am doing this. Any better ideas would help. Am planning to have a separate NSDictionary with the tweet id. And, then check in that to see whether the tweet id exists or not. Based on that, will insert that into list. I think it is better that traversing through the list and getting the hashmap again.

Comment: @user694688 Better would be to have a single array which contains the keys (ids) in order to maintain your order, but the messages themselves are within a single dictionary (id/message pair).  This gives many advantages.

Comment: Sorry, i  did not get what you are suggesting.

Comment: @user694688 Rather than an array of dictionaries, you have one array and one dictionary.  The array keeps the order and the dictionary keeps the data.  The only issue here is that if you want to remove an id (a tweet) you have to remove from both, but other than that it should be a simple and effective solution.

Comment: Thanks, i think this is the same solution i have asked above in one of my comments. The idea is to have a separate dictionary of tweets and manipulate the list accordingly. Am i correct?

Comment: @user694688 Sorry I can't see that comment.

Comment: This is that comment: Am planning to have a separate NSDictionary with the tweet id. And, then check in that to see whether the tweet id exists or not. Based on that, will insert that into list. I think it is better that traversing through the list and getting the hashmap again.

Comment: @user694688 Yeah sounds right.  If it does already exist, however, you will need to remove it from the array an re-insert it at the front.